# Stack Overflow giving question ban despite upvoted and accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Is Stack Overflow being unfair with its "question ban", if I have only 2 questions which have been downvoted, and 5 questions total?

I have contributed almost 60 answers, 12 of which were accepted.

It feels like I've given a lot of time to this site, and when I need help with something, it's not there for me.

Could it be a bug, or is SO really this strict?

Comment: Describe "unfair"?

Comment: How many of your questions are deleted?

Comment: That seems weird, and you indeed have a solid track record of answers. Are you sure you don't have deleted downvoted contributions?

Comment: I've given you a helping hand there, but seeing as you are used to answering and not **asking**, perhaps you should review the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , before you ask your question?

Comment: Giving time to the site in the form of answers doesn't mean you're allowed to ask crappy questions.  The standard of questions is just as high for regular answerers as it is for brand spanking new users.

Comment: "How many of your questions are deleted?"
None that i'm aware of.

Comment: My question wasn't about finding out how to get out of this ban, i have read the help topics on this, and i know the ban cant be lifted by request. The question was if its a bug and if other users think if this ban is too strict. 
2 downvoted questions = ban ?
That seemed like a bug, or at least unreasonably strict.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: Could you help me to get out of the question ban? I have contributed to the site constantly. Stackoverflow is so toxic

Comment: @myworldbox Unfortunately, the best we can do to help you without breaking rules is guide you toward improving your existing questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions != Answers.

Bans for answers and questions are separate things. If you are perfectly capable of answering questions at a sufficient quality, but you can't seem to get the hang of asking them, the system will stop you when asking more questions. But you can still answer.

Exact details aren't public, but while I can imagine the system taking your overall contributions into account when asking a question, if you've asked several poorly evaluated ones it should still stop you at some point. No matter how good you are at answering.

So yeah, Stack Overflow really is that strict. Try to read up on how to ask good questions, improve those you've asked, and once you manage to get the ban lifted (if Oded's actions didn't already take care of that) you should be good to go.

Comment: can you tell me how I get away from question bans? I really hate this site and the modator.

Comment: I am contributing to the site and the site banned me. Why?