# What triggers the question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

When will I know I'm getting close to a question ban? Is there an average question score or minimum to watch for? And how much rep do I need to get out of it? Is there not something that indicates that? I can understand if it's hidden.

Comment: Your focus should be on improving your question quality, not trying to figure out the banning system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We don't disclose the exact algorithm.

Why?

Because that would allow people to skirt close to it without triggering it. Or try to circumvent it. Or argue and complain about it (even more than they already do, that is).

It will remain hidden.

Comment: Well that's an answer, but you can't give information about something like `you got X downvotes, you need maximum 10*X rep to get out of it`? It isn't discover the algorithm itself, but get a 100% way to get out of it.

Comment: The only thing you need to know is that you get question banned for asking "poorly received questions." So either don't ask questions that don't follow the rules, or fix your existing questions. If you have to worry about the specifics, it's already not looking good for you.

Comment: @KugBuBu- I've said everything I have to say about this. I will not disclose any details beyond those already public.

Comment: @gunr2171 I am OK with answers so I tried to go out of it with answers a bit right after it, and nothing.

Comment: Keep trying. You'll get there eventually.

Comment: @Bart http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255162/stack-overflow-giving-question-ban-despite-upvoted-and-accepted-answers/255165#255165, that somehow doesn't apply to my situation?

Comment: pfft. I know the algorightm. If User.IsAnnoying == 1 {Ban(User)};

Comment: @CalvinSmith How do you measure User.IsAnnoying? :p