# What to do regarding users posting low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, question-quality

A certain user keeps posting low quality plzsendmetehcodez type of questions. I added a comment on one of his posts telling him what to do but he seems to have ignored it and posted another plzsendmetehcodez type of question.

What is the right thing to do in this situation?

- Add another comment and keep bugging him in his posts?
- Flag for a moderator? (I don't want to burden the moderators that much.)

As a noob myself I quite understand some users committing mistakes on their first posts but I think 9 low quality questions such as the questions this user posted is a bit too much.

Comment: Just keep closing/downvoting. A question ban will kick-in for sure.

Comment: Bugging him obviously isn't working if it has become a chronic problem. Just downvote and flag the questions for closure. Pick any reason that is appropriate. We have automatic mechanisms in place to handle these types of users that will eventually be tripped.

Comment: Most of his questions are code dumps so I am not sure. Is it alright to flag, let's say 3 of his posts as low quality? Or rather is serial flagging alright?

Comment: I edited one question that seemed  worth rescueing, I casted a close vote on all others.

Comment: As their reputation is below 125 (might be 150, not sure), the user should be rate limited on posting questions anyway, so they won't be able to keep on posting crap questions for long. And as rene mentioned, if the questions they do ask are downvoted and closed a full question ban will eventually kick in.

Comment: related: [What triggers the question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255578/what-triggers-the-question-ban)

Comment: related: [Is it okay to close questions that provide too much code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272128/is-it-okay-to-close-questions-that-simply-provide-too-much-code?cb=1)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just keep downvoting and voting to close. A question ban will kick in for sure.

Comment: also provide reason like "teh question was incomplete, plz provide full detailz and what hav u tried b4" lol

Comment: That won't work for questions slightly above borderline, which get heavily upvoted instead.

Comment: @simonzack: Are you suggesting that there is a better course of action than downvoting and voting to close?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett No, but I wish there was.

Comment: @simonzack Wait, questions... get upvoted? Since when? :p

Comment: @neminem Rep whores.