# Is it okay to close questions that simply provide too much code?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Quite often, I see a question that is asking for an answer to a specific, answerable problem. They provide enough information for an answer to be possible... but that's just the problem. These people provide *too much* code. They dump their main class with twenty unrelated methods into a code box, type up their problem, and call it a day.

This question doesn't seem to be inherently off-topic. The question isn't necessarily unclear, and it might even be quite specific. They have isolated a specific problem that needs to be solved, so it doesn't fit the "why isn't this code working?" close reason. It's not really too broad, either, since the problem is often quite exact, it's just horribly difficult to trace through their mess of code and figure out where their problem lies.

Is it valid to close these questions with the following close reason?

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Clearly, they have not provided the *shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem,* but that seems a tad subjective anyway. Should I just downvote and move on, or should I attempt to take action to close these questions?

Comment: Can a good answer be provided for the *next* person who has this problem?

Comment: @MichaelT Theoretically, but that's true for most questions that would fit the close reason I quoted. However, these tend to be questions that are extremely specific (perhaps once fitting into the "too localized" umbrella), so often it's a fairly unique problem, anyway.

Comment: I think it's perfectly justified to cast a close vote on questions that contain a lot of code that is clearly unrelated to the question. The reason you quote sounds like the right one to me. The "shortest code" phrase applies perfectly. Yes, it's somewhat subjective, but there are plenty of questions where it's a clear call because the amount of code is so much more than necessary.

Comment: "unclear what you're asking because TL;DR" seems a good vtc reason.

Comment: Not to mention, dumping a ton of code without taking the time to verify where the error is shows no or little effort.  They tend to be, "debug my code for me plz" questions.

Comment: If it's a good question with too much code, I usually ask the OP to reduce their code to an [MCVE, and provide the link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If they don't do it within a day or two, or at least provide some justification for including the code that appears unnecessary, I'll come back and downvote. I usually don't flag though, if the underlying question is clear and focused.

Comment: I basically asked this same question ([meta link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272164/884412)) yesterday, about a specific question of my own. But, why do you assume that _all such questions_ have not provided the shortest possible code? If it comes from a huge project, it's often hard to write a 10-line MCVE. I got exactly this kind of comments yesterday, after working for 2 hours to reduce my problem to a minimal example (which prompted the question on meta) -- and further debugging proved that even this (big) example wasn't actually small enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's _always_ okay to close, if you think there's a reasonable case for it, because, after all, you're just voting. If you're wrong, others won't agree and the question won't be closed. This is one of the reasons I like Stack Overflow; sometimes it's nice to be a part of the Hive Mind.

Comment: Yay caching; this question has a score of 19 here and 15 in the Hot Questions

Comment: Not only questions, also many answers. SO being a coding-questions-site does not make it ok to almost spam code everywhere. Besides many connected problems, it *should not be allowed to simply answer by "try this code"*. **An answer should answer the question and only that**. Nothing more nothing less. Answer it in the most understandable way possible and not making one search for the actual answer in some lines of code, sometimes even snippets (seriously - either all the snippets stop or ther needs to be a way to hide everything but n lines from a given snippet).    My opinion of course ;)

Comment: Also some question-threads focus on the specific example becaus of that. And when people get redirected there from other duplicate the answers won't help them at all. But yeah, starting to minimize 100 line questions is a good start

Answer (score 29):

I think a little case by case reasoning is needed for these. Try to ask why the OP is dumping all this code.

If the OP:

1. Thinks that the context of the problem is required to answer the question

   - Or they think that their problem is a unique snowflake, and they want an answer that fits into their wall of code without having to adjust it.

In this case some simple direction and a suggestion that the OP should edit should work.

---

2. Is looking for an answer to one specific bug, in a wall of bug ridden code.

   - They have several issues and can't fully untangle them.

Ask the OP to cut the code down to one bug at a time and remind them that they can ask follow up questions if need be. If this doesn't work vote to close as "Too broad".

---

3. Has copied the wall of code from someone's project and they don't fully grok it yet.

   - This is probably the most common case, they may understand the bit that they're asking about, but they aren't yet sure how the other bits work and are unsure if they are related to their problem.

This is one occasion where I really miss "Lacks Minimal Understanding", but I think these fit into the "Questions seeking debugging help" close reason.

Comment: Often, while in the process of whittling down a problem to make a concise reproducible test case, free of clutter and distractions, the problem is discovered.  I know I certainly have done this many times.

Answer (score 7):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

This close reason is for questions like this: [viewWindow property in google charts not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013158/viewwindow-property-in-google-charts-not-working)

"It isn't working" isn't useful, there should be an explanation of what the error is, what the person has done to try to isolate it, and what if anything they've found out about where it isn't.

Basically, use that close reason only when someone is:

1. Asking "Why isn't this code working?" **and**
2. Doesn't supply an error that explains what isn't working **and**
3. Doesn't supply a minimal complete and verifiable example

If someone is asking a question with lots of code in it (like this: [New Zealand Geocoordinates Duplicated on Geochart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322276/new-zealand-geocoordinates-duplicated-on-geochart) ), but the question isn't about debugging, that close reason probably isn't appropriate. Because it doesn't match those three criteria.

Just having a ton of code isn't necessarily a bad thing if the reason for the code being there is clearly stated and doesn't obscure the problem. If the issue with the code is that it makes it impossible to see what the problem the asker is facing is to the point where the code isn't helping, the feel free to close as *Unclear what you're asking*. If the issue is that the huge chunk of code is in there because the person is expecting someone to rewrite several different related functions to solve the problem, then it may be a good time to consider *Too Broad*.

If you just think the person is dumping a bunch of code there because it's easier and they haven't even bothered to try solving the problem on their own or making it easier for folks to help them, a downvote works too.

Comment: Your second point should be extended to "doesn't supply a _complete_ and _correlatable_ description of the error". I'm mostly active in python and java, where thousands of questions contain only the exception message without a stacktrace, or worse, somebody dumps a huge amount of code and a stacktrace and we have to find out the line numbers where the actual exception happens. Btw, your example for "lots of code" isn't actually lots of code, just 5 lines of code and a lot of data.

Comment: @l4mpi, feel free to edit then! I am not a programmer, so if you have a better example, and better criteria for how to include code, I would love to see you make my answer better.

Comment: Well, I don't know any example of a good question with lots of code off the top of my head, and I don't exactly feel comfortable putting words in the mouth of a diamond user when it comes to criteria for closevoting questions (the official stance on this is confusing enough already), so I'll pass. Regarding the code amount, I'd say the problem is _unrelated_ code - if a "minimal example" happens to be long, that's usually fine.

Comment: @l4mpi, I'm a diamond user because I'm a community manager (I work for Stack Exchange) -- this doesn't mean I am the arbiter of right and wrong, I posted a lot prior to getting hired too. You shouldn't feel uncomfortable editing anyone's post if you are improving it. Including diamond folks. Editing is designed in to the system for a reason, and you should feel comfortable doing it (and if not, we should find ways to make you feel more comfortable doing it because it's an important part of how the system works). Anyway, I made the edit about the error/explanation, hope this makes sense.

Comment: You gotta admit, it says a lot that a non-programmer is able to identify and articulate what makes a good on-topic programming question better than a large portion of programmers ever will.

Comment: You say all three points must hold for that off-topic reason. The way read it, it's more than sufficient if only point 1 (kind of question) and one of the others (minimal requirements missing) hold.

Answer (score -8):

I feel that the question can still have value to to others. Just because the author of the question has an overly verbose and specific question, it does not mean that the question does not have value. If some brave soul goes through and figures out what was wrong (or just recognizes the symptoms and works back from there to find where the error is), they can answer the question (and, if they are very generous reduce the question to just the relevant parts).

Later on, when someone else has similar symptoms and searches for an error message or code, the answers in the question may be helpful.

Comment: The fact that someone with very much time on his hands can extract a valuable question from such a dump does not make the question which actually exists any more useful or less in need of radical editing.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed, because part of the value of SO is for others who have the same problem. It'll be hard for them to ascertain that their code is similar to the wall of code.