# Large algorithm with many helper functions.. how much code should I include?

Tags: discussion

As the title suggests, I have a very large algorithm that has many helper functions that I'm trying to optimize. I've ran several profiling functions that shows me how much time is being spent in each helper function. The profiling has identified one helper function in particular as the cause for the bottleneck. I would really like to post this to the SO community, but I'm not sure if I should include the entire algorithm with every helper function (for reproducibility and full transparency) or simply post the troublesome helper function. I've read this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272164/4408538), but this seems like a different situation.  My helper function can run in isolation and I know that this function is the cause for the bottleneck, I just want to know if the community would like to see the full algorithm or simply have a look at a 20 line function that doesn't seemingly do anything exciting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The minimum possible to help you resolve the issue is desired. Possibly a description of the algorithm and the problem function would be best to start. Remember, folks can always ask for more if they feel it is needed. Anyway, [this related meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-code-optimization-help) might be worth a look

Comment: For what purpose do you want to post it I wonder? What question would you ask that needs your life's work to be posted?

Comment: @codeMagic, the question you referenced was very helpful. As I am very new to the SO community and programming in general, I was unaware of a Code Review site.  After reading through the comments/answer for that question I think that my question would be a good fit for Code Review.  However, I am having trouble finding information for determining which site is most appropriate.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Gimby, my ultimate purpose is factoring extremely large numbers (not an easy thing), and the implementation that I'm currently trying to improve is none other than the [Quadratic Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve).

Comment: @Joseph Here are a couple links that might help you decide whether the question should be asked on Code Review: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/3-questions-in-stack-overflow-comments-pointing-to-code-review and http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1689#1689 You'll also what to look at their [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help topic, and indeed the entirety of the their help section on asking...