# What purpose do "debug this" non-minimal questions have and how should they be handled?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am asking about a specific kind of question: on-topic but lacking an MVCE in the sense that the code provided is far from minimal, it's the actual long and noisy code of the OP.

> The following code is supposed to do some task, but instead it [doesn't compile/segfaults/spawns kittens/...].
>   `A long non-minimal code`
>   How do I solve this issue?

This kind of question is almost always too specific to be of any use to anyone else. They may boil down to a simple issue which has already been answered, in which case closing as duplicate could maybe be possible.

Thus,

- Is StackOverflow the right place for this kind of question?
- How should they be handled? The best thing I can think of is creating the
  MVCE from their code, editing the question to make it more general,
  but it's a large and tough amount of work and the edit is likely to be
  rejected or too harsh.

Comment: not going to cast a close vote yet, but doesn't this cover the same ground: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272128/is-it-okay-to-close-questions-that-simply-provide-too-much-code

Comment: 1. No. 2. Vote to put it on-hold with the appropriate pre-canned response.

Comment: AH! Thanks @Tanner, I didn't find it! I'll mark it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the following close reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.