# Methods for discouraging systematic poor questions

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, question-quality

[Multiple](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274645/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-ask-about-complete-basics) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255261/how-to-answer-extreme-beginner-questions) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262055/was-i-and-stack-overflow-being-too-strict-and-unreasonable-in-closing-this-que) [on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255261/how-to-answer-extreme-beginner-questions?lq=1) [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271086/what-to-do-regarding-users-posting-low-quality-questions) SO touch upon the issue of simplistic questions, saying that the standard approach is to down vote these questions, since a lack of research isn't a valid reason for closing.  There's no good way to stop "hit-and-run" simple questions, and since such questions often come from first-time users who may not understand how this site works, a heavy hand isn't warranted.  I agree with this stance, but in the case of a user who is systematically doing this, I wonder if stronger action is warranted.  Yes, the down votes affect rep, but this may not affect behavior and with +5 for up votes and +2 for marking an answer, it isn't hard to maintain a positive rep.

So, let's say there is a user who has been asking a large number of questions that are very, very basic, to the point that a trivial level of research would answer them.  In this case, the system is being abused by repeatedly having others solve your trivial problems.  Should there be further recourse in such a case?  Intrinsically linked to this is whether such questions are harmful to the site as a whole.  I would say yes, since they discourage users from putting in due diligence before asking questions in the first place.

I'd rather this discussion stay conceptual, assuming a user who was clearly not doing any research before asking straightforward questions.  But for those wondering, yes this has come from a recent case I observed.  A user had several questions that were very, very simple.  The language in question was the first one I learned, so I know that it is extremely user-friendly and designed for those with no programming experience.  Furthermore, it has extensive built-in documentation with examples.  The user's questions are all detailed and of reasonable quality except that they could have been solved with a couple of minutes of reading.  In one instance, the user commented on an answer with a follow-up question, which was responded to with a link to documentation that amply answered the question.  Rather than reading it, the user posted another question the next day to get a direct answer to that question.

Comment: You might want to search for "question ban" "answer ban" and "rate-limiting". Someone who keeps submitting posts that keep getting a net negative score (more downvotes than upvotes, independent of reputation changes) will soon find themselves rate-limited and eventually banned. There are provisions to deal with those that just dump their account to create a new one.

Comment: From [worldofjs 's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274725/2564301) in one of the linked questions: "The action you should take is to **downvote the question** (for lack of research effort), and then answer it should you choose to do so." This seems most appropriate to me as well.

Comment: @Louis except that it often doesn't work, as long as the user is able to format their question, include enough information to make it answerable (too much is often fine, even) and express it in somewhat decent english. Too many people upvote those kinds of questions nowadays; downvoting because of lacking research effort is almost nonexistent or cancelled out, in my experience. I've recently stumbled across an user with >800 questions (at a rate of approx. 5 per week) which were mostly extemely basic documentation or debugging issues, and while none had a high score only few were negative.

Comment: It is not very common.  But yes, some users have the unusual combination of being able to write effectively but never once look at a manual.  They avoid the usual question ban by attracting "looks good" upvotes on their questions.  You can flag a moderator, use the "custom" option and ask if anything can be done to slow the user down.  The moderator typically first follows up by sending the user a warning.

Comment: ...see also: [What triggers the question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255578/what-triggers-the-question-ban)

Comment: @gnat amazingly, that question isn't one of the several I had found on this topic.  This one is a bit different since the only problem with the questions is that they lack research, but since the answer seems the same, this might be a duplicate.

Comment: if you're interested in more related discussions, these questions are worth looking at: [Off topic questions have to be cleared out of the way, but NOT via closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure) and  [Help us test question triage!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage)